# Execute swift on Ubuntu

Tags: swift, ubuntu, executable

I have downloaded the official release of Swift for my Ubuntu (16.04).
I would like to execute the file `/path/to/swift/usr/bin/swift`.
I type `./swift` in this directory and exec format error appears.
Doesn't matter whether I run it directly (`./`) or change `$PATH` and type `swift` anywhere the same error appears.

Is it a problem of Swift at all?
Or is it the matter of my Ubuntu or this executable file?

UPDATE: the exact error is: `bash: /swift-3.0/usr/bin/swift: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

The `file` command reports:

```
/swift-3.0/usr/bin/swift: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
```

`uname -a` says:

```
Linux Lenovo-B570 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:05 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What does `file /path/to/swift/usr/bin/swift` print?

Comment: /swift-3.0/usr/bin/swift: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped

Comment: And `uname -a`? Also, please update you question with the *exact* error message you're getting.

Comment: Linux Lenovo-B570 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:05 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial for installing swift 3](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/install-swift-3-ubuntu.html) from the Vapor framework docs.

Try uninstalling swift and reinstalling using

`curl -sL swift.vapor.sh/ubuntu | bash`

from the link

> Note: The install script adds Swift to your ~/.bashrc profile automatically.

You should be able to run swift files after running the above command.

***Note:** If this doesn't work then we can identify that the installation is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't work, but it probably is not the matter of swift.  Trying to find the answer I realized that I have 32-bit Ubuntu release, the executable file is 64 bit (Keith, thanks). Is there any way to run it on this system better than running virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run a 64-bit executable (x86-64) on a 32-bit system (i686).

That won't work (though you can usually do the reverse with a typical setup).

You need to find and install a 32-bit version of Swift. (Or, if practical, consider updating your system to use a 64-bit OS.)